# Is data() guaranteed to be equal to &front() for nonempty strings?

Tags: c++11

I often use std::string as a generic binary buffer. This causes problems with obtaining a mutable data pointer as you can't use `&s.front()` when the string `s` is empty.

That's why I have this helper function (which does what string::data should do in the first place):

```
char* data(string& s)
{
    if (!s.empty())
        return &s.front();
    else
        return const_cast<char*>(s.data());
}
```

This is consistent with the standard, because strings are stored contiguously and you are not allowed to overwrite the terminating 0 character.

I like it because it seems the size check gets optimized away.

But I would like this function even more:

```
char* data(string& s)
{
    return const_cast<char*>(s.data());
}
```

I'm just unsure whether it's actually legal to do this.

There's no doubt it'll work and I would have used this version if the size check didn't get optimized away.

Comment: Use `std::vector<char>` as a buffer, `std::string` is not supposed to be used for that.

Comment: @Xeo I find strings more convenient. It provides basically the same functionality, but makes your strings automatically buffers without needing to copy them. Also Google's Protocol Buffers use them [link](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#scalar) that kind of got me into them.

Comment: This is screaming **undefined behavior** all over the place. Don't do this. Don't promote this. And don't ever work on my team. You will not survive day 1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The standard says `data() == &operator[](0)` which is the address of the reference to the first character. `&front()` is also equivalent to `&operator[](0)`. `operator[](0)` returns a reference to the first character, so it doesn't matter if it's constant or not, their addresses have to be equal.

But now I'm not completely sure whether you are actually allowed to modify the string through the returned pointer (even though now I know it points to modifiable data). I'm almost sure you can since the function takes a nonconst reference, but that's for another question if I can't figure it out.

It's incredible how many subtleties are involved in such a simple one line function.

Comment: The standard ($21.4.7.1) prohibits modifying this data: `const  charT*  data()  const  noexcept; ... Requires: The program shall not alter any of the values stored in the character array.`

Comment: @mockinterface I don't think that's relevant since you have the nonconst string as a parameter and the data() returns a pointer which has to point to front() for nonempty strings, so can modify it because you have access to nonconst version of front(). Why should it matter how you obtained the pointer?

Comment: Passing an instance by a nonconst reference doesn't permit you to do things prohibited by the standard. To illustrate - if I place a cat in a cat resort while I'm on holidays I expect them to feed and bathe it, but not shave its fur. Cats aside, I am not familiar with a library that doesn't allow you to mutate the string buffer - many people engage in that sort of practice, but the language of the standard is clear.

Comment: @mockinterface Standard explicitly allows you to modify pointers to nonconst data members, even through const pointers (that's what const_cast is for). So my understanding is your quote applies only to const strings (yes it's redundant) or it would be a contradiction in the standard. But it would be nice to have another opinion on this as we probably won't resolve it here.

Comment: `front()` returns a non-const reference to the first **character**. You are free to alter that first character until you get bored. The pointer retrieved by taking the address must not altered. Performing any sort of arithmetic on the pointer is undefined behavior, even if you never dereference it. Dereferencing this modified pointer is likewise undefined behavior.

Comment: @IInspectable: I knew it was you even before you commented. But that wasn't the question. Read the title, please. My answer that the addresses are equal is correct. What are you mentioning is for another question I didn't manage to formulate yet.

Comment: No. The question is: Are they equal (in all aspects). And the answer is: No, they are not. Seriously, what you are doing is craptastic.

Comment: @IInspectable: Whatever, even though it wasn't what I meant, I understand you may view it as that. Still, you didn't provide a single argument. Why should it matter how you obtained the address? It doesn't. As long as you point to a modifiable thing, you are allowed to modify it. Consider this example `void f(int const* i) { *(int*)i = 0 };` this is legal if you always pass `int*` to that function.

Comment: C++ doesn't have rules for kicks. They are there for a reason. If you willingly write code with undefined behavior you are taking it up with the optimizer. The optimizer **always** wins. You are one of those brave souls that have to learn it the hard way. You'll understand once you have spent countless weeks hunting down a bug that the numbnut sitting next to you has implanted, with his *I know what I'm doing* mindset.

Comment: I see you're having fun downvoting my questions for no reason. Grow up, be a man. Downvote my **answers** instead.

Comment: @IInspectable: I think you are just making your own rules up. The section about `const_cast` specifically says that as long as the pointed variable is nonconst, you are allowed to modify it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44289/discussion-between-iinspectable-and-user2345215)

Answer (score 0):

One quirk which I think has not been noted. And this would seem to be an extreme edge case I only worked out by closely reading. `string::data` guarantees that the buffer it returns contains the string plus a null terminator. `std::string` however does not guarantee a null terminator to its buffer.

Therefore I believe a technically conforming implementation could not add a null terminator when the string is created or when calling `string::front` and only add it when a call to `string::data` or `string::c_str` is made.

Therefore even if the pointer you get is the same, I am not sure the side-effects are guaranteed to be the same, making these not necessarily equivalent. (before someone asks how this would work on `const` strings, I don't see why a confirming implementation could not declare the internal buffer `mutable` and modify the null even for `const` functions assuming it performed appropriate locking to make simultaneous access safe.)

However an implementation that actually did this would seem either highly ill designed or actively cruel.

Comment: Adding the null terminator as a "`mutable`" side effect of `c_str()` would violate the standard library rule on data races. It was conforming up to C++03 though.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Would this be the case even if the library took appropriate precautions to synchronize the change? Perhaps with an internal mutex? (I do realize this is going into obsurdity, but I am keen to know if this is actual a possibly confirming behavior)

Comment: [res.on.data.races]/3: "A C++ standard library function shall not … modify objects accessible by threads other than the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function’s non-`const` arguments, including `this`." and /5: "A C++ standard library function shall not access … elements of its container arguments except by invoking functions required by its specification on those container elements."